# How does android.provider.CallLog.Calls store its numbers?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

So my problem is that I'm trying to delete all call logs associated with a given number. In the Android API, android.provider.CallLog.Calls stores all the calllogs, and a context resolver (ctx.getContentResolver()) has a delete function that lets you delete whatever calllogs satisfy your conditions.

However, since I'm not sure how android.provider.CallLog.Calls stores its numbers (eg, with or without whitespace, hyphens etc) I don't know how to run a comparison on the number. Here's my current code:

```
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
                        "number='"+numbers.getLong(i)+"'", null);
```

The API here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#NUMBER) describes the number as "The phone number as the user entered it" which doesn't really help me.

Any thoughts on how I should tackle this issue?

Thanks,
Khalid

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try out some code and see what you get back? My guess is that since the number is stored "as the user entered it", there will not be any dashes, as they simply just dialed the numbers.

Comment: Alas, I don't have an actual phone to work on. The emulator produces the number as just a number (no dashes etc). It doesn't work on my client's phone though, and I'm /guessing/ this might be why.